# LLDP on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: networking

I want to connect RaspberryPi to a switch (like Cisco, Dlink, TPlink, etc.) on a network and then check from Pi if the switch is connected to the Pi.

To do this, I am thinking of doing the following :

1. Enable LLDP on the switch
2. Install lldpad on the Pi and perform these steps:

   `apt-get install lldpad`

   `lldpad -d`

Run the following script:

```
  for i in `ls /sys/class/net/ | grep 'eth\|ens\|eno'` ;
  do echo "enabling lldp for interface: $i" ;
  lldptool set-lldp -i $i adminStatus=rxtx ;
  lldptool -T -i $i -V sysName enableTx=yes;
  lldptool -T -i $i -V portDesc enableTx=yes ;
  lldptool -T -i $i -V sysDesc enableTx=yes;
  lldptool -T -i $i -V sysCap enableTx=yes;
  lldptool -T -i $i -V mngAddr enableTx=yes;
  done
```

After this I want to receive TLVs/PDUs from the switch. This will tell me if the switch is still connected to the Pi. However, I don't know how can I achieve this step? What commands to run from Pi to get PDUs from the switch?

Answer (score 2):

You show LLDP messages with the LLDP client `lldpcli`

Example:

```
sudo lldpcli show neighbors

sudo lldpcli show statistics
```

Ref.: https://docs.cumulusnetworks.com/cumulus-linux-41/Layer-2/Link-Layer-Discovery-Protocol/

Comment: How do I get the command `lldpcli` on a raspberry pi?

Comment: apt-get install lldpd to get lldpcli